# Ubuntu 16.04 GUI failure after dist-upgrade

Tags: 16.04, unity, upgrade, gui

I have been using Ubuntu on my laptop since I bought it several years ago, no changes in hardware for at least 12 months.

Last night after running `sudo apt dist-upgrade` (which I do at least once a week), the Desktop (default Unity) froze so I switched to a terminal (`<ctrl><alt><F1>`) and ran `sudo shutdown -H now`.

After rebooting, Unity won't start, instead I get the following:

```
partn-root: clean, 452504/5047920 files, 3373456/20120576 blocks
[  9.178656] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64 error -110
```

Googling the above turns up problems with booting from USB devices.  I have no USB devices plugged in when I get this error.  In fact, I can boot Ubuntu (including the Unity GUI) successfully on this computer using a USB stick.  This + the fact this problem occurred immediately after a dist-upgrade leads me to believe I have some sort of driver problem following the upgrade.

What can I do to diagnose and fix this problem?

Comment: Based on other reading I've done around this problem, I thought I'd try disconnecting the battery, which involved opening up the computer.  Left the battery unplugged for more than 30 minutes then reconnected it and reassembled the computer.  Unfortunately the problem remains.